# ERROR! docker container' is not a valid attribute for a Play

Tags: docker, ansible

Iam just writing simple ansible playbook to run container getting error

This is my playbook code

```yaml
---

- name: Create container 
  docker_container: 
     name: mydata 
     image: busybox 
     volumes:
       - /data
```

Getting error like this.

> ERROR! docker container' is not a valid attribute for a Play

Anybody help please.

Comment: Your example is not a valid playbook but a single task in a top level list. => https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks.html

Comment: Have you installed the community docker container plugin? Check the documentation here please https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/docker/docker_container_module.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some more lines to your playbook.

```
- name: Play name
  hosts: your_hosts
  tags: your tag
  gather_facts: no|yes
  tasks:
    - name: Create container 
      docker_container: 
         name: mydata 
         image: busybox 
         volumes:
            - /data
```

If you haven't yet, [do](https://galaxy.ansible.com/community/general?extIdCarryOver=true&sc_cid=701f2000001OH6uAAG):
`ansible-galaxy collection install community.general` where you are running the playbook (Ansible host).

Then, `ansible-playbook [your_playbook.yaml]``

Notice if you are using `volume` you may want to use `docker_volume` module to config it before the container starts. Also, try to map the volume, like `- /data:/my/container/path` so you can find it easier.